# PHP MongoDB lot of inserts per second

Tags: php, mongodb, bigdata

I need to write some lightweight script that can handle lot of inserts to database. Around 300 per second.

It's simple counter of data (like view counts etc). So for instance call request:
http://example.com/count/param1/param2/param3/param4

I need to save param1..4 with some extra data (like ip address or user agent).

I decided to choose MongoDB as primary database. My idea is to only write data without with some basic validation of parameters like: `if(param1..4 are ok) than insert`. Validation is pretty simple (is_int(), param2 == 'view') etc.

After an hour I would like to loop through all my database records, remove duplicates, collect some data like how many hits per hour and put it to mysql database + clear looped items from mongo.

I'm not specialist in such big data processing. First of all here is my code for mass inserting:

```
$m = new \MongoClient($connectionString);
$db = $m->stats;
$collection = $db->statsdata;
$collection->insert($arrayOfData);
```

My question is - is it optimal? Would it handle 300 requests per second? As I assume each request will open connection to mongo database insert data and close it. Is it any way to, I don't know, keep this connections open only for write for instance?

Second question is about parsing the data. I thought that it would be optimal not to check if record exists before write. Just write all data and after that parse it through. Is this solution ok?

Do You have any more input about handling such solutions? Maybe use another database or approach? Any input will be appreciated:)

Comment: Check [bulk inserts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-inserts/). But the way you described it, I doubt MongoDb will be the bottleneck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is - is it optimal? Would it handle 300 requests per second?

Yes, your code is fine. 300 inserts a second is not a lot of inserts for MongoDB.

> As I assume each request will open connection to mongo database insert data and close it. Is it any way to, I don't know, keep this connections open only for write for instance?

No. The PHP Driver uses persistent connections.
Only one connection (per server, per database) is create for each PHP process.
You should not explicitly close connections as that will cause you performance impact.

> Second question is about parsing the data. I thought that it would be optimal not to check if record exists before write. Just write all data and after that parse it through. Is this solution ok?

There is a way to "upsert" (update-or-insert-new-document), depending on the data you have, that may be something for you: http://php.net/mongocollection.update